# Unhandled Exception java.io.iOException

Tags: java, android, ioexception

I am getting unhandled exception `java.io.IOException` at compile time. I have posted the code below and pointed out the error line. I searched many post regarding to this issue but I don't get any relevant solution.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...................
}

public void startRecording() throws IOException {

..................
}

player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        if (RecordFile != null && ifexist.equals("true")) {
        }                                              
        else {
            if (isRecclicked == true) {
                recordButtonPressed = true;

            try {
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override  
                    public void run() {
                        // this code will be executed after 2 seconds

                        startRecording(); ----> Unhandled Exception java.io.iOException
                    }
                }, 2000);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put code of startRecording .. Its crashing over there

Comment: @PreethiRao no crashing in startRecording() method.its compile errror

Comment: @steve1 show the startRecording() method..if there is no need for IOException then...try remove from throws IOException or you can put the IO Statement under try catch block instead of throws IOException...actually u throws the exception and not handle in the activity

Comment: try solution posted by @User404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
try {
      startRecording();
    }catch(IOException ex) {
    //Do something with the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `startRecording()`, which, I assume, can throw an `IOException`, but you didn't specify that an `IOException` can occur inside `public void run()`. It should be fixed if you surround `startRecording()` with a try-catch block.